# Why is it in vb.net if I assign a number to a single variable it does not equal the same value

Tags: .net, vb.net, floating-point

I have been searching the internet trying to understand in its simplist form why this behavior happens.

```
Dim mysingle As Single = 456.11
Dim mybool As Boolean = mysingle = 456.11
```

In the lines above mybool becomes false. I found this behavior when putting the single into a double I found extra digits showing. The .net documentations states a single is an approimate value :S

I gatehr a single is a 32bit floating point number? But why are extra digits appearing when I have explicitly said what the number is.. surely the memory should store that numbers either side of my number are 0 to fill up the memory location?!

My brain is fried on this one :(

Answer (score 10):

The value being compared in the second statement isn't considered a `Single`, rather it's being treated as a `Double`. Since you're using VB.NET you can suffix it with a `!` to force it to a `Single` and this will return `True`:

```
Dim mysingle As Single = 456.11
Dim mybool As Boolean = mysingle = 456.11!
```

Comment: +1: This is completely true - the problem is from doing double/single comparisons.  However, the reason this is a problem is due to floating point precision - understanding that will make this answer much more obvious.

Comment: @Reed thanks, definitely in agreement with you on that point.

Comment: It's curious that both vb.net and C# generally forbid assignments from `double` to `single`, but allow assignments in the reverse direction as well as direct equality comparisons, notwithstanding that the latter are far more fraught with peril than the former.  Coercing a double to a single may cause a loss of precision, but all numerical operations can cause such loss, and the loss won't generally be a problem except when numbers are converted back (which should IMHO require a cast).  Which would more surprising results: `Dim x As Double = someInt/10.0f` or `Dim y As Single = someInt/10`?

Answer (score 9):

I recommend reading:  [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

It explains the issues with precision in floating point math in detail.  For a simpler variation on the above, see [The Floating Point Guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/).

Answer (score 2):

Another good reference for understanding floating-point in .NET: https://csharpindepth.com/articles/FloatingPoint

Let me highlight his point on comparisons:

> One consequence of all of this is that
> you should very, very rarely be
> comparing binary floating point
> numbers for equality directly. [...]
> One simple way of doing this is to
> **subtract one from the other, use
> Math.Abs to find the absolute value of
> the difference, and then check whether
> this is lower than a certain tolerance
> level.**